# Setting a class property to an Enum value

Tags: groovy, enums, grails-domain-class

I have a abstract groovy class that I would like to have an attribute that is of type Enum.  However, I'm not clear on how to get it set up.

I have This:

```
abstract class Person { 
protected int heightFeet, heightInches, weight
protected String firstName, lastName
protected OccupationType occupation

protected Person(int hf, hi, w, string fn, string ln, int ocp){
        this.heightFeet = hf
this.heightInches = hi
this.weight = w
this.firstName = fn
this.lastName = ln
this.occupation.value = ocp
}
```

and the Enum looks like this :

```
public enum OccupationType {
   Teacher(1), Administrator(2), Counselor(3), Doctor(4), Nurse(5), ...
 OccupationsType(int value) {this.value = value}
 private final int value
 public int value() {return value}
}
```

So I Typically get some sort of NullPointerException that it cannot set a value to null object.  Not sure what I'm missing, or if this is at all possible.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot set property 'value' on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.setProperty(NullObject.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setProperty(InvokerHelper.java:192)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:480)
    at ***.****.***.****.<init>(**.groovy:30)
    at ****.***.***.****.<init>(***.groovy:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at buchwalter.oldschoolgame.characters.FighterTest.getFullConcrete(FighterTest.groovy:18)
    at buchwalter.oldschoolgame.characters.PlayerTest.shouldReturnGenderType(PlayerTest.groovy:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Share your code that throws null pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `Person` constructor. You can't set the attribute of an enumeration. You just pass the enumeration object to the constructor OR you pass the integer `value` attribute and `find` the enumeration object which has that value. I've cleaned your example, but it should work when you add the remaining constructor parameters:

```
// this won't work because 'this.occupation' IS null
protected Person(int ocp) {
  this.occupation.value = ocp
}
```

So either pass the enumeration object:

```
protected Person(OccupationType type) {
  this.occupation = type
}
```

OR receive an int attribute and `find` it:

```
protected Person(int ocp) {
  this.occupation = OccupationType.find { it.value == ocp }
}
```